# adding commands to custom control for button binding wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a method to my custom control which I can call from a button using command binding, in my MainWindow.xaml. I've come across a few solutions online, however one of them didn't appear to work and the other did. Can someone explain to me the correct way to set this up. The first solution produces and error as mentioned below. The second solution works but I'm not sure of any pros/cons.

**Solution 1 - broken**

```
public partial class MyControl : Control
{
    ...
    public static readonly RoutedCommand AlignLeftCommand = null;

    static MyControl()
    {
        binding = new CommandBinding();
        binding.Command = AlignLeftCommand;
        binding.Executed += new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(AlignLeft_Executed);
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(MyControl), binding);
    }
}
```

Error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property...

**Solution 2**

```
public partial class MyControl : Control
{
    ...
    public static readonly RoutedCommand AlignLeftCommand = new RoutedCommand();

    public MyControl()
    {
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(MyControl.AlignLeftCommand, AlignLeft_Executed, null));
    }
}
```

Here is the button calling the method.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="Left Edges" FontSize="8"
            Command="{x:Static JM:MyControl.AlignLeftCommand}"
            CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=mycontrol}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Is your application MVVM or code-behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you should define a **command binding** on the `Window` like that(create handlers for `Executed` and `CanExecute`events):

```
<Window x:Class="CommandBindingWPF.MainWindow"
        ...The code omitted for the brevity...
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
```

and declare your `Button` ix xaml:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Button Command="ApplicationCommands.New">New</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Handlers should be created in code-behind after you command binding created:

```
private void CommandBinding_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Hello from Command");
}

private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{      }
```

**Update:**

For MVVM application:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Then create a property in your viewModel. For instance:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand YourCommand { get; set; }
    public YourViewModel()
    {
        YourCommand = new RelayCommand(DoSmth, CanDoSmth);
    }

    private void DoSmth(object obj)
    {
        Message.Box("Hello from viewModel"); 
    }

    private bool CanDoSmth(object obj)
    {
       //you could implement your logic here. But by default it should be  
       //set to true
       return true;
    }
}
```

And XAML should be look like:

```
<Button Content="Click me!" Command="{Binding YourCommand}"/>
```

To get acquainted with MVVM, I recommend you to read Rachel Lim's blog. She has a talent to teach people and she can explain by simple terms. [Read Rachel Lim's blog.](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/)
To get acquainted with MVVM commands [see that post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example)

Comment: The command function actually exists within my control though. How can i properly set that up?

Comment: i dont think this answers the question completely.

Comment: @JokerMartini is it MVVM or code-behind application?

Comment: Not super important really . Ideally close to mvvm if possible

Comment: ideally close to mvvm

Comment: @JokerMartini please see my updated answer. Feel free to ask any question

Comment: @Super I can send you my actual code that I'm trying to implement the solution to. I think that will help clear things up more. I have used relay commands in the past, however the problem in question is regarding a custom Control which compiles into a DLL. then i then use in my application. I dont know if your answer would still apply

Comment: @JokerMartini can you upload to onedrive and share a link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102736/discussion-between-jokermartini-and-stepup).